# need explanation on the usage of nested Obx method of getx dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, flutter-state

There's list in flutter tree & when i click one of the items, if not previously selected then i add to an observable list, but i am not able to get updated value from `isCurrentPageSelected` method without using second `Obx` & have to wrap `GestureDetector` widget. any idea why is that?
The  controller is working fine & as expected for UI doesn't seem to update with 2nd `Obx` in tree.

````
Expanded(
              child: Obx(
                () {
                  return pagesController.isLoading.value
                      ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                      : Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                          child: GridView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            gridDelegate:
                                const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                              crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                              mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                              crossAxisCount: 2,
                              childAspectRatio: 9 / 12,
                            ),
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              var page = pagesController.pagesModel[index];

                              return Card(
                                child: Obx(
                                  () => GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () => togglePageSelection(index),
                                    child: AspectRatio(
                                      aspectRatio: 9 / 16,
                                      child: AnimatedOpacity(
                                        duration:
                                            const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                        opacity: pagesController
                                                .isCurrentPageSelected(
                                                    page.id)
                                            ? 0.3
                                            : 1.0,
                                        child: Image.network(
                                          '***.jpg',
                                          loadingBuilder: (context, child,
                                              loadingProgress) {
                                            return loadingProgress == null
                                                ? child
                                                : const LinearProgressIndicator();
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                            itemCount: pagesController.pagesModel.length,
                          ),
                        );
                },
              ),
            ),
    ```
````

Comment: ah, looks like I will have to re-write the app using bloc.

Comment: Bloc is good, but I'd personally recommend Riverpod.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you've been looking for in the minimum viable way. The list is updated using one Obx builder.

In the below-written code, I'm updating the value of a property named `tapCount`. & objects of those properties stored in the observable list.

Source code:

```
class NewHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<NewHomePage> createState() => _NewHomePageState();
}

class _NewHomePageState extends State<NewHomePage> {
  RxList<Model> modelList = <Model>[].obs;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    modelList.addAll(
      <Model>[
        Model(title: "title 01", subTitle: "subTitle 01", tapCount: 0),
        Model(title: "title 02", subTitle: "subTitle 02", tapCount: 0),
        Model(title: "title 03", subTitle: "subTitle 03", tapCount: 0),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView.separated(
          itemCount: modelList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Obx(
              () {
                final Model model = modelList[index];
                return ListTile(
                  dense: true,
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.star),
                  title: Text("title: ${model.title}"),
                  subtitle: Text("subTitle: ${model.subTitle}"),
                  trailing: Text("tapCount: ${model.tapCount}"),
                  onTap: () {
                    model.tapCount = model.tapCount + 1;
                    // Important 
                    modelList.refresh();
                    // Important 
                  },
                );
              },
            );
          },
          separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return const Divider(height: 1, thickness: 1);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Model {
  Model({required this.title, required this.subTitle, required this.tapCount});
  
  final String title;
  final String subTitle;
  int tapCount;
}
```